# How does being in first class help in Jordan’s drug situation?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

On a flight to Geneva in *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), Donnie speaks to Jordan Belfort, who had awakened
from the effects of drugs and found himself fastened to a seat:

> Donnie: You called the captain the N-word. Yeah, he was very upset.
> **Luckily we're in first class**.

How does being in first class help in Jordan’s drug situation?

Comment: Think about the quote you have included here - being a rich first-class passenger doesn't help with the drug situation, but it does means that the captain was relatively lenient and overlooked being called a racist slur.

Answer (score 3):

In the [source novel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(book)), Belfort tried to sexually assault a stewardess. Luckily, his friends had brought plenty of 'walking-around money' and with the assistance of their government contacts they were able to convinced the Swiss authorities and airline Captain that it would be in the best interests of all concerned that Belfort be let go without charge.

> The Frog cocked his head to one side and fixed me with a look that so much as said, “You are one demented bastard!” But all he said was, “We would wish you not to contact the stewardess while you are in Switzerland. Apparently she is…how would you say it in English…she is…”
> “Traumatized?” I offered.
>
> This is the word we would use. We would wish that you please do not contact her under any circumstances. I have not the slightest doubt that you will find many desirable women in Switzerland if that is your goal. Apparently you have friends in the right places.” And with that, the Captain of Wishes personally escorted me through Customs, without so much as stamping my passport.

The implication in the book (and film) is that an *ordinary citizen* would have been decanted straight into the arms of the local police and jailed.